# How to make a static Calendar thread safe

Tags: java, static, calendar, thread-safety

I'd like to use a Calendar for some static methods and use a static field:

```
private static Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Now I read java.util.Calendar isn't thread safe. How can I make this thread safe (it should be **static**)?

Comment: Is your static calendar just a fixed date?

Comment: maybe it would help to make it "volatile" ?

Comment: no, I just don't want to create so many instances - for every call to my methods, as that possibly could take time.

Comment: You mean you are worried about the performance hit of many calls to the constructor?

Comment: Yes, not at least as the code is for mobile devices..

Comment: I am beginning to conclude that Calendar should not be regarded as simply "not thread safe."  It should be labeled "thread hostile".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't make something thread-safe if it isn't. In the case of `Calendar`, even *reading* data from it isn't thread-safe, as it can update internal data structures.

If at all possible, I'd suggest using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead:

- Most of the types are immutable
- The immutable types are thread-safe
- It's a generally much better API anyway

If you absolutely *have* to use a `Calendar`, you could create a locking object and put all the access through a lock. For example:

```
private static final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
private static final Object calendarLock = new Object();

public static int getYear()
{
    synchronized(calendarLock)
    {
        return calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }
}

// Ditto for other methods
```

It's pretty nasty though. You could have just *one* synchronized method which created a clone of the original calendar each time it was needed, of course... it's possible that by calling `computeFields` or `computeTime` you could make *subsequent* read-operations thread-safe, of course, but personally I'd be loathe to try it.

Comment: If you clone a template, you dont need synchronized block.As the template itself is immutable.

Comment: Even though a read on Calendar updates internal state, can you give an example of when two threads might try to set different values for that state?

Comment: @bestsss: Well, that depends on whether clone itself is thread-safe. Given the lack of thread safety in the rest of `Calendar`, I wouldn't want to rely on it.

Comment: @Peter: Imagine if `areFieldsSet` becomes *visible* as `true` to one thread due to the computation in another before the computed field values themselves become visible. It would potentially be possible for one thread to read *some* old field values and *some* new ones, leading to weird results. I don't like trying to reason about implementation details to decide whether or not that's possible.

Comment: @Jon, I agree the class is complex enough that its hard to determine all the possible things which could go wrong. It has some long fields, non volatile fields which could be read incorrectly if changed.

Comment: @Jon, `clone()` is threadsafe (in a way that can be called concurrently with itself), i dont know a single class (in the JRE) that alters its internal state during `clone()`. Perhaps unclear, if you have a template you just clone() it. If you need to alter the template, clone it, alter it, replace the reference (needs volatile, or better AtomicReference w/ CAS)

Comment: @bestsss: I would *expect* `clone()` to be thread-safe, but given the nastiness of `Calendar`, I'd lock to be sure anyway. Or rather, I'd just avoid using `Calendar` to start with :)

Comment: @Jon, dunno why the backlash to Calendar, never ever had issues with.

Comment: @bestsss: It's got a horrible API, it's not thread-safe, it doesn't let you represent all the different kinds of date/time you might want to represent, it's mutable... it's wrong in just about every way I can think of. Joda Time is *so* much nicer. (There are still flaws in Joda Time, some of which I'm hopefully removing in Noda Time, but it's a lot better than `Calendar`.)

Comment: @bestsss Well you have to admit that the Calendar API is hardly the best ever designed (starting from trivial stuff like months starting with 0, days with 1) and does make "simple" stuff harder than it should be. That combined with the fact that in this case an immutable class is much easier to work with - well I agree

Comment: @Jon Argh too slow ;) But what do you mean with "it doesn't let you represent all the different kinds of date/time you might want to represent"? I thought Joda Time used an identical internal representation, so what do you mean with that?

Comment: @Voo: How do you represent "just a date with no time" in java.util.Calendar, in an expressive way? (LocalDate in Joda) Or "just a time, with no date" (LocalTime in Joda), or "just a date/time with no associated time zone" (LocalDateTime in Joda)? What about an interval, or a duration?

Comment: @Jon, being mutable is good , you know that's mutable, why would you expect to be threadsafe then? Mutable and threadsafe means datarace that has to be solved somewhere. `long time` is immutable, cheap and perfectly threadsafe. This is what I use if I need time. Calendar is useful only for human representation having a timezone in mind, not for internal storage. Totally cool w/ that. I guess people consider the API awkward but it gets the job done for me.

Comment: @bestsss: Being mutable is *not* good. It makes it *far* harder to reason about any data you hold, as it could be changed at any point. That's why `String` is immutable... Personally I don't *want* to represent times just as `long` values - I want to have an object which expresses what I know about it *in the type system*.

Comment: @Jon Ah that was what you meant. I thought you meant Joda time used a different internal representation. I agree that combining date and time in one class with no alternative isn't pretty - though I've got no idea what a time without a timezone would be (isn't that pretty useless as its ambiguous? [as soon as the data is used in different timezones we have a problem] But then the whole affair is awfully complicated and I'm no expert)

Comment: @Voo: My alarm clock could be set to wake me up at 8 o'clock local time every day, wherever I am. What time zone should that use in its representation? ;)

Comment: @Jon, Then we have misunderstanding: calendar doesn't hold data, it processes it. Even its name doesn't suggest to hold data (at least not to me). I admit I have not read (or recall) the preamble of `Calendar` doc but to me it's just a translator from human form time (i.e. Thursday, 3:15pm) to a moment in time that's universal (and represented by miillis since 1970UTC). If I need to keep the timezone for some reason, still not Calendar. Special Time representation a simple Pair of long/timezone (or id of) would do.

Comment: @Jon *What time zone should that use in its representation*, you sync the timezone externally based on your location. Meh, so smth like onTimeZoneChange - recalc awaking time.

Comment: @bestsss: But logically it *doesn't have a time zone*. Why should it be represented in *any* time zone? What's the relevant information here: "8am in whatever your local time zone is". That information doesn't change when I change time zone, so why should any representation change? Moreover, why should the representation *pretend* that it's specific to a particular time zone? Having worked on calendaring systems, I can assure you that being able to represent these things separately is incredibly important.

Comment: @Jon, *doesn't have a timezone* is a rule, not time (again at least to me). I take the time only as universal (UTC based) and seriously never had issues with that part. You have human based representation 8am+local TZ. The variable is the zone, it changes, the UTC value does as well. It's a simple logic to follow, any variable changes the result of the function changes. After the result of the function UTC long time, nothing extra needs to be done just checking if the currentTime >= awakingTime.

Comment: @bestsss: So in the example of a time without a date, what UTC value are you going to use? Something with a specific date? Bear in mind that a particular local time may occur zero, once or twice on a specific day when applied to a specific time zone. The concept of a value not being associated with any time zone - but equally not being a fixed *instant* in time - it an important concept to be able to express, in my view... the set of logical operations you can do with such a value is different to (say) an instant in time with no associated zone, or a particular zone+date+time.

Comment: @Jon, *Something with a specific date* - never. time only or any local timezone, etc.. it's the same: human vision of the time, it has to be represented internally at some point (i.e. the date/year +timezone applied). Once the missing info is available (date+timezone), a valid time is available as well. How to store prior (int hours, int minutes, int millis, or just a single int holding all the info, millis since mightnight) is a minor issue, i.e. I'd write a class to store it till the moment it can be represented as real time (UTC based), at that moment grab a calendar and set it up-> `long`

Comment: @bestsss: If it's just a time but you're trying to represent it as UTC, what's your epoch going to be? You talk about "millis since midnight" but that's not a UTC-based time. You talk about writing "a class to store it till the moment it can be represented as real time" - exactly. You want to represent the concept as a type. Now, with a decent date/time API, you don't have to do that yourself. It's part of the library. But I disagree that the date/year+timezone needs to be part of the internal representation. Why should it be?

Comment: @Jon, of course some rules+data may not suffice the standard API. As you see I say: Calendar doesn't hold data, and I seriously don't care for. If I understand the problem, coming up w/ any datastructure is no issue. The calculation processes (i.e. what calendar does) is no walk in the park though and I am totally happy with. The good part about such approach: it is very portable and easy to grasp.

Comment: My firm wrote its own date/time classes, largely (AFAICT) duplicating Joda Time. We have TimeOfDay, ZonedTimeOfDay, etc. and, yes, they are immutable. Instances where we have to use java Calendar for conversion are bottlenecks. Even though it's Java's second try at datetimes, it still isn't that good.

Comment: @bestsss: Well, I'd rather use a type which allows me to express the value *and* perform operations on it in one go, ideally without having to write it myself. Joda Time performs such a task admirably. Why use Calendar when something so much better is available? Why use a `long` when you can describe your data so much more expressively?

Comment: @Andrew: Was there any reason not to use Joda Time, out of interest? (Perhaps it pre-dated Joda?)

Comment: @Jon, long is the most portable part you can get; like I told, it is an easy concept to grasp and totally portable (java, C, C#, objective-C - it's the same more or less). Could be me, but I am no huge fan of external APIs (also need to port 'em, not myself in particular but yeah); I can think of MiG layout, jzlib +some ApacheHTTP as the only libs we use.

Comment: @bestsss: Yes, it's very portable... and doesn't express anything about the value it's going to represent. Do you use arrays of bytes instead of strings, as well? ;) Personally I think it's really important to know the best way of performing a task on the given platform. There's a reason these APIs exist: they mean the world doesn't have to make the same mistakes time and time again. There's a portability issue when data has to be *transmitted*, certainly - but in many other cases it's not a problem, IMO... whereas having to use a bad API (such as Calendar) can lead to horrible bugs.

Comment: @Jon, *Do you use arrays of bytes instead of strings, as well?*, Dunno how to answer that, since we use heavily hacked (mostly by me) tomcat and the case there is exactly like that (ByteChunk)... I didn't mean the transmission of the data but representation - the concept of millis since 1970UTC is super simple and portable.

Comment: @bestsss: Yes, that's nice and portable if all you want to represent is an *instant* in time. That's fine for a time stamps, but not for something like a repeated event which is always at the same time *in a particular time zone* etc. Trying to force many different concepts into the same type is a mistake that both Java and .NET made, in my view. Working with dates and times is hard enough without having to battle a poor API :(

Comment: @Jon, well, the decision predates _my_ arrival at the company. I think there was a reluctance to use 3d-party FOSS, which I do not share. I doubt if anyone even evaluated Joda Time. And, BTW, your reply to bestsss is exactly what we need to deal with, and why the Java classes are no darn good.

Answer (score 3):

Calendar is thread safe provided you don't change it.  The usage in your example is fine.

It is worth noting that Calendar is not an efficient class and you should only use it for complex operations (like finding the next month/year) IMHO: If you do use it for complex operations, use local variables only.

If all you want it a snapshot of the time a faster way is to use currentTimeMillis which does even create an object. You can make the field volatile if you want to make it thread safe.

```
private static long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The usage is a bit suspect.  Why would you get the current time and store it globally like this.  It reminds me of the old joke.

> - Do you have the time?
>   - Yes, I have it written down somewhere.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "change it" bearing in mind that *reading* from it can change its internal state? I wouldn't be entirely surprised to find that two simultaneous read operations could *potentially* end up corrupting state. It's unlikely, but I wouldn't like to rely on it. Calendar is a nasty, nasty class :(

Comment: Reading it won't change its state in inconsistent ways.  If you were worried about this you would have to say the same thing about String.hashCode().

Comment: I agree that Calendar is nasty. Have you tried Serializing it? It sends the entire TimeZone information which is not great for performance but it means if you have a system which has up to date TimeZone information, but you read an old Calendar or get a Calendar from a system which is not up to date you get subtle TimeZone issues you never expected to happen due to bugs in code you are not running. :P

Comment: See my comment replying to you in my answer. `String` is designed to be thread-safe, so its hash caching is thread-safe: the value is atomically changed from "uncached" to "the cached value". Compare that with `Calendar`, where a `boolean` field determines whether the fields are set, and the fields themselves are separate. What guarantees that all changes to that set of data occurs atomically, or in a desirable order?

Comment: I also have a database app in which date/times are stored in a UTC numeric format.  Every time I need to show a date to the user, the code for that table needs a way to map from a UTC number to a localized String.  For that I've been using Calendar because TimeZone provides historically accurate DST and TimeZone offsets.  Because I have so many classes that need this conversion and because Calendars are expensive to create, I've also been using a static Calendar field in my JulianDay class used to do the date localizations.  Really struggling how to make this API thread safe.

Comment: @scottb Part of what makes Calendar slow is creating the TimeZone and Locale objects.  If you cache these immutable objects, you can make creating new Calendar faster.  To make Calendar thread safe you need to lock it while using it.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

`Calendar` replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). [Immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), so [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

```
private static ZonedDateTime someMoment = ZonedDateTime.now();  // Capture the current moment as seen in the JVM’s current default time zone.
```

If the value is meant to be fixed, unchanging during the execution of your app, mark it `final`.

```
private static final ZonedDateTime someMoment = ZonedDateTime.now();
```

If at runtime you might assign a different object, then for thread-safety use an [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).

```
private static final AtomicReference< ZonedDateTime > someMomentRef = new AtomicReference<>( ZonedDateTime.now() ) ;
```

Later updating with a fresh moment.

```
someMomentRef.set( ZonedDateTime.now() );
```

If you need to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert.

```
ZonedDateTime someMoment = someMomentRef.get() ;
Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.from( someMoment ) ;  // `GregorianCalendar` is a concrete subclass of `Calendar`.
```

## `java.time.ZonedDateTime`

The terribly flawed `java.util.Calendar` class has been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically replaced by `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

A `ZonedDateTime` object represents a date with time-of-day as seen in a particular time zone.

Understand that a time zone is a named history of the changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians. An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the temporal meridian of UTC.

To get the current moment, specify your desired/expected time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

If you want the JVM’s current default time zone, use `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

You can store a `ZonedDateTime` object in a `static` reference. But be aware that such an object stores a frozen moment, is immutable, and does not adjust to later moments. If you want a later moment, call `now` method ago to generate a new fresh `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
private static final ZonedDateTime appLaunched = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) );
```

## `java.time.Instant`

If you merely want to track a moment, a specific point on the timeline, without business rules explicitly aimed at time zones, use a moment as seen in UTC. For that, use `java.time.Instant` class.

```
private static final Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Always in UTC, an offset of zero.
```

## Generating localized text

You can later apply a time zone for presentation to the user.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) ;
String output = 
    zdt
    .atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() )  // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .format( 
        DateTimeFormatter
        .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )  // Returns a `DateTimeFormatter` object.
        .withLocale( Locale.getDefault() )
    ) ;  // Returns a `String` object.
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Yes, you could synchronize on it, but it still has mutable state fields. You'll have to create your own Calendar object.

If possible, use something lightweight, like a long measuring the times in milliseconds, and only convert to a Calendar when you NEED to.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to make the `Calendar` API thread-safe, use the thread-safe `java.time` API introduced in Java 8 instead. This API also provides a more fluent and intuitive interface for date and time manipulation.

Here's an example compatible with the legacy `Date` API of getting the start of next day with the `java.time` API:

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public static Date getStartOfNextDay() {
    final ZonedDateTime startOfNextDay = ZonedDateTime.now()
            .plusDays(1)
            .withHour(0).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
    return Date.from(startOfNextDay.toInstant());
}
```

And here's how it looks with the `Calendar` API:

```java
import java.util.Calendar;

public static Date getStartOfNextDay() {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Comment: I do not see how using `LocalDateTime` in this code adds value. The replacement for `java.util.Calendar` is  `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @BasilBourque, on a second glance, my answer is a unintentional copy of your answer. What do you think, should I remove mine in favor of yours?

Comment: Leave it. You've gotten an up-vote. An alternate example does not hurt. And your Answer inspired mine.  I do suggest you add a bit of explanation of the code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The API in the code snippet looks quite readable and fluent, and the code appears to be self-explanatory - don't you think so?

Answer (score -1):

Create a `Calendar` as a local variable in the method. If you need the same calendar across methods, you may be using statics where a (singleton or quasi-singleton) object would be more appropriate.

Comment: Are you really suggesting that making a singleton of a mutable, non-thread safe object will help make its class thread safe?  Really?