# Is java.util.Calendar thread safe or not?

Tags: java, calendar

I've been working under the assumption that neither `Date` nor `Calendar` are thread-safe, but, during a recent discussion, a co-worker told me `Calendar` was thread-safe.

So, I did some research, and came up with nothing. There are plenty people arguing it's thread-safe, and plenty people arguing it's not thread-safe. And, to top it off, the documentation doesn't say anything one way or another, not for `Calendar`, nor even for `Date`.

So, which is it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245053/how-to-make-a-static-calendar-thread-safe see that

Comment: @AlexColeman Note that the first answer says "no", the second answer says "yes", and none of all that discussion is backed by anything.

Comment: +1 for `Joda Time` though. If thread-safety issues are your concern then using this would be a good option.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral However, the first was upvoted 8 times and got the correct answer, and seemed to be backed well

Comment: @AlexColeman The first answer is by Jon Skeet, so it's subject to the Jon Skeet effect. And there's no backing: is there any code or explanation or reference to official documentation showing it isn't thread-safe? No. It mentions mutability, which does impact thread safeness, but the question was about the *static* `getInstance`, not about `Calendar` instances themselves. So, no, that isn't an answer to this question.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious I will point out that each call to Calendar.getInstance() will return a new object. So as long as you use your instance within a single thread, thread safety may not be an issue for you.

Comment: @mojoken At risk of stating the obvious, thread safety pertains to multiple threads using the same instance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is a link to the source code of [Calendar](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Calendar.java.html) and [GregorianCalendar](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java.html) in Java 7

If you read the code you will see that none of the instance methods are synchronized, and none of the instance fields are `volatile`.  You will also see that even the field `get` methods can cause a Calendar instance to mutate.  And since there is no synchronization performed, different threads may see stale versions of a Calendar object's fields following such a mutating operation.

For the record, the mutation action in the field get methods happens in / during a call to this method:

```
 1555 protected void complete()
 1556       {
 1557           if (!isTimeSet)
 1558               updateTime();
 1559           if (!areFieldsSet || !areAllFieldsSet) {
 1560               computeFields(); // fills in unset fields
 1561               areAllFieldsSet = areFieldsSet = true;
 1562           }
 1563       }
```

In short, the `Calendar` class is not thread-safe, and `GregorianCalendar` isn't either because it inherits the non-thread-safe fields and methods.

But don't just take my word for it.  Do your own analysis of the source code.

---

> And, to top it off, the documentation doesn't say anything one way or another, not for Calendar, nor even for Date.

If the javadocs don't specify the thread-safety of a class, then you should *assume* that it is not thread-safe.  (Especially if the class is mutable *by design*.)

Answer (score 4):

Documentation from Oracle says nothing about thread-safety: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html.

OpenJDK source code (build b147) implements `java.util.Calendar` in a non-thread-safe way, for example:

```
public void setTimeInMillis(long millis) {
  // skipped
  time = millis;
  isTimeSet = true;
  areFieldsSet = false;
  computeFields();
  areAllFieldsSet = areFieldsSet = true;
}
```

I think that it's safe to assume that the class is **not** thread safe.