# Java TimerTask already scheduled or deleted

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

I have a client-server clock application in Java. The server sends time data to all connected clients, each connection running on a separate thread. The timed event is managed by ClockTask, which is singleton, so that all connection threads have access to the same server time:

```
public class ClockTask extends TimerTask {

private Calendar calendar;
private String time;
private static ClockTask instance = null;


public synchronized static ClockTask getInstance()
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        return new ClockTask();
    }
    else return instance;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}


public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}


private ClockTask()
{
    this.calendar = Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("us", "US"));

}  


@Override
public void run() {

    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");                   
    this.time = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    //System.out.println(time);
}


public void setCalendarTime(String newTime)
{ 
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");   
    try {
        Date t = dateFormat.parse(newTime);
        calendar.setTime(t);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



}
```

Now, if I connect more than one client, I get this TimerTask already scheduled/deleted exception.

My Server code, together with its connection thread: The server loops indefinitely, waiting for new clients, if a client connects to the socket, it starts a new thread.

```
public class Server {



 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    boolean listeningSocket = true;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(11111);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 11111");
    }


    while(listeningSocket){

        System.out.println("Waiting for a client to connect...");
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected!");
        ConnectThread ct = new ConnectThread(clientSocket);                     
        ct.start();

    }
    System.out.println("closed");
    serverSocket.close();       
}

}
```

The connect thread uses an existing ClockTask instance to get and send the current server time.

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread{

public static final int INTERVAL = 1000;

static ClockTask ctask;


private Socket socket = null;
public ConnectThread(Socket socket) {
    super("ConnectThread");
    this.socket = socket;
    ConnectThread.ctask = ClockTask.getInstance();
    System.out.println(ctask.getTime());

}

@Override
public void run(){
ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = null;
ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = null;
try {           
    serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());          
    serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(ctask, 0, INTERVAL);

    while(true)
    {
        Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
        System.out.println(ctask.getTime());
        serverOutputStream.writeUTF(ctask.getTime());               
        serverOutputStream.flush();
        String ok = serverInputStream.readUTF();
        if(ok.equals("ok"))
        {

            String newTime = serverInputStream.readUTF();
            ctask.setCalendarTime(newTime);
        }

    }

} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    try {
        serverOutputStream.close();
        serverInputStream.close();              
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}       
}
}
```

Here's what happens:

```
Exception in thread "ConnectThread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or         cancelled
at java.util.Timer.sched(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Timer.schedule(Unknown Source)
at task2.ConnectThread.run(ConnectThread.java:36)
```

This is probably because I use the same TimerTask to schedule the timer more than once. Any idea how to resolve it? I'd really appreciate someone gettick back to me on this, as I really have little time. And this is the very last thing I need to finish.

Comment: Your `ClockTask` singleton pattern is flawed when used in a multithreaded env, recommended some reading. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern for java I use `enum singleton pattern`

Comment: okay... do you think the use of synchronized is recommended?

Comment: if you're relying on it being a singleton for your implementation then yes. Not saying it's the answer to your problem, hence a comment :-)

Comment: Well, I'd like to do some reading... but I'm really pressed on time. Any advice that is a bit more direct would be greatly appreciated. It's the 4th time I'm raising problems with this exercise, I'd really like to finish it.

Comment: if it's an exercise, then you should definitely go do some reading rather than me give you the answer

Comment: Also another problem is `Calendar` is not thread safe either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131324/is-java-util-calendar-thread-safe-or-not

Comment: Okay, I read what you've posted. How is enum going to help me in this problem? I don't understand. I wouldn't be asking here for feedback, if I was able to do it just by reading stuff.

Comment: The enum singleton pattern allows for thread safety when creating a Singleton. It can also be done with `synchronised` as you said

Comment: I've done it, and changed the constructor to private. But the same stack trace appears.