# Is nesting of locks necessary for this code?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety

I have two shared mutable objects in a class whose thread safety policy has been defined as "thread safe."

```
public static final GregorianCalendar CAL = new GregorianCalendar();
public static final SimpleDateFormat  SDF = new SimpleDateFormat();
```

The intent is to reduce the number of object creations as these objects are expensive to create and the methods that will need to use them are expected to be frequently invoked.

Here is one such (static factory) method:

```
    public static MJD ofTimeStampInZone(String stamp, String form, TimeZone tz) {

        double result;

        synchronized(lockCal) {
            synchronized(lockSdf) {
                CAL.setTimeZone(tz);
                SDF.setCalendar(CAL);
                SDF.applyPattern(form);

                try {
                    Date d = SDF.parse(stamp);
                    CAL.setTime(d);
                    result = (CAL.getTimeInMillis() / (86400.0 * 1000.0)) + 
                            POSIX_EPOCH_AS_MJD;
                } 
                catch (ParseException e) 
                    { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parsing format"); }
            }
        }
        return new MJD(result);
    }
```

I have also set a policy for this class that the `lockCal` must always be acquired before `lockSdf`.  However this is also true of this class:

- CAL can be locked and used without SDF, in which case SDF is not locked.
- SDF is never used in a method unless CAL is also used

Because SDF is dependent on CAL, I am wondering if locking on `lockCal` alone is sufficient to prevent data inconsistency during concurrent access.  This would allow me to dispense with the locking on SDF.  In other words, is thread safety still guaranteed, with the conditions above, if I use only:

```
    public static MJD ofTimeStampInZone(String stamp, String form, TimeZone tz) {

        double result;

        synchronized(lockCal) {
                CAL.setTimeZone(tz);
                SDF.setCalendar(CAL);
                SDF.applyPattern(form);

                try {
                    Date d = SDF.parse(stamp);
                    CAL.setTime(d);
                    result = (CAL.getTimeInMillis() / (86400.0 * 1000.0)) + 
                            POSIX_EPOCH_AS_MJD;
                } 
                catch (ParseException e) 
                    { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parsing format"); }
        }
        return new MJD(result);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any other code which uses double locking on `lockCal` and `lockSdf` ?

Comment: Yes, I have two other methods which lock on `lockCal` and then `lockSdf`.  I have several methods which lock on `lockCal` only, but these methods do not mutate the state of `SDF`

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippets.  You don't need to show us everything, just something along the lines of what you showed us for `ofTimeStampInZone`

Comment: _whose thread safety policy has been defined as "thread safe."_ - but those classes are not thread-safe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131324/is-java-util-calendar-thread-safe-or-not and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @Ruslan: there is no requirement that a thread-safe class must not be composed of components which themselves are not thread-safe (in fact, thread safe classes are composed out of mutable, non-thread safe classes (eg. ArrayList) all the time).

Comment: @scottb, Yes. I read it by mistake as "GregorianCalendar and SimpleDateFormat are thread-safe". Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SDF` is only ever used by a thread that has already acquired `lockCal`, it can only be accessed by a single thread at a time, i.e. it is thread safe even if you remove the lock on `lockSdf`.

If you choose to rely on this observation, you should document it clearly, so future maintenance programmers don't start to use `SDF` outside of a `synchronized (lockCal)`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, thread safety is not guaranteed here. Assuming that SDF should be guarded by lockSDF, but the it's modified under a different lock, another thread might not see the result of the changes of SDF if it acquires only lockSDF.
But you have a policy: acquire lockCal before lockSdf. Looks like it "kind of" solves the problem, but

1) It makes reasoning about thread-safety too hard

2) It makes lockSdf useless

Assuming that SDF is dependent on CAL and CAL is guarded by lockCal, then it would make sense to also use lockCal for guarding SDF.

*Java Concurrency in Practice (Brian Goetz):*

**Summary of Part 1**

> ...
>
> Guard all variables in an invariant with the same lock.
>
> ...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer.  You make an important point about potential visibility issues for SDF when guarded by lockCal.  But are you saying that if SDF is dependent on CAL that it is acceptable to lock both mutable objects with the same lock?

Comment: @scottb, yes, it is acceptable and actually it is the recommended way. I updated my answer with a quote.