# Independent time in java application

Tags: java, android, multithreading, time, jodatime

I would like to set arbitrary time in application. Time is downloaded from server in milliseconds format- it should be independent from `locale` and other system preferences.
But application reacquire thread safety solution, and object like standard not thread safety `Calendar` object.

Whats is the best way?

Today I use:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
calendar.setTimeInMillis(serverTime);
```

But is not good way for me beacuse, is't thread safe.

**tl;dr**
Program have to contain own internal clock fetching time from external server. Clock must be thread-safe.

Comment: _But is not sufficient for me._ What are you missing?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking but `currentTimeMillis()` isn't locale/time zone dependent, so it might be used.

Comment: If you need a thread-safe alternative to Calendar, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). Reference: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6245086).

Comment: @user2558882 yes, but you might present sample code

Answer (score 1):

The time in milliseconds that a [Java application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) uses is

> the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time
>   known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

This number is based on the GMT time zone. If you need to print it in another time zone you can use any formatting class you want, say `SimpleDateFormat`. If you need to make the variable that holds it thread safe, just synchronize on it, possibly by wrapping it in a class.

```
public class TimeInMillis {
    private volatile long time;

    public void setTime(long time) {this.time = time;} 

    public time getTime() {return time;}
}
```

Whenever you need to display it, just get the `TimeInMillis` object, get the `time` and create a `Calendar` object with it. Then use a formatting class to print the time in the format, locale, timezone, you require.

Comment: What do you think about use something like `JodaTime` class `DateTimeUtils` ?

Comment: The `synchronized` is not needed.

Comment: +1 This answers the question of how to store the time in a thread safe manner.  How you download it and how you display it are different questions and should be confused with this IMHO.  BTW You could make it an enum like `public enum TimeInMillis { INSTANCE; // etc. `

Answer (score 0):

> Time is downloaded from server in milliseconds format- it should be independent from locale and other system preferences

That isn't "time". That is a timestamp, meaning a particular time value reported by a particular piece of software at a particular point in time.

Now, if you are trying to say that, in future communications with this server, you want to translate time as reported by the device into the timebase as known by the server, *that* makes at least a bit of sense. In that case, you compute the delta between the device time when you receive the timestamp and the time value in the timestamp itself. Then, you apply that delta to future times you report back to the server.

> Program have to contain own internal clock fetching time from external server

That makes no sense whatsoever.

In this universe, based on our current knowledge of physics, time is continuous and linear. Time does not change only when you are "fetching time from an external server". Again, what you are "fetching... from an external server" is a timestamp, a statement of what the clock on the server thought the time was at the time you made the request. You can use that timestamp for comparison purposes with other timestamps from that server, and you can use that timestamp to compare to the device's current time to determine the difference.

However, you cannot create hardware in Java code, and so you cannot create "internal clock" in Java code. The only clock is the device's clock. As noted earlier, you can *translate* the device's clock's time to the timebase of the server by applying the aforementioned difference, but the passage of time is still being marked by the device's own clock.

Since the difference is going to be an `int` or `long`, you can use `AtomicInteger` or `AtomicLong` if you are concerned about multiple threads working with the value at once.

Answer (score -1):

I would just the the time in milli-second with GMT (BTW computers don't support UTC as such)

```
long serverTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // millis since 1/1/1970 GMT.
```

To get/set this in a thread safe manner you can make it `volatile`

BTW Calender is pretty slow even on a PC.  I would avoid using it on a phone.

Comment: Sorry, application have to download time from server.

Comment: And that can be parsed into GMT time in millis.

Comment: I'm thinking `currentTimeMillis() - serverTime`

Comment: @user902691 is the question how to download the time, or is it how to store/use the time in a thread safe manner?

Comment: @KEYSER You don't understand me at all, application should have own time synchronized from external clock. Similar to NTP.

Comment: @PeterLawrey How store, and how use it like standard calendar.

Comment: @user902691 The OS already synchronizes from an external time like NTP.  I assume you mean you want to use a time given to you by the server?  If you want locale/timezone independent times you shouldn't be using Calendar. Just using a plain `long` unless you can tell me why you need more.