# Java get Time parts from a Long representation efficiently

Tags: java

I know I can use the following code to translate a long to Data and get its hour part:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(long-variable);
c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

But this is really not efficient, and since this code runs from multiple threads I cant just reuse the Calendar object, is there a more efficient way to get the hour part from a long representation of a date?

Thanks!

Comment: A `long` representation doesn't have a time zone associated with it - a `Calendar` does. The `long` representation is *just* an instant in time. The current instant in time would have an hour-of-day of 13 for me in the UK, but it could be somewhere else entirely for you... which time zone are you interested in? Your current code uses the system default time zone - are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: `(longvar/1000/60/60)%24` ? You'll get the hour in GMT, of course.

Answer (score 2):

The `Calendar` is not thread safe,so `Calendar` instance should be synchronized while multiple thread.Of course,using `ThreadLocal` is good at performance.Like this:

```
private ThreadLocal<Calendar> calendar=new ThreadLocal<Calendar>(){
    @Override
    protected Calendar initialValue() {
        return Calendar.getInstance();
    }
};

public void foo(){
    Calendar c = calendar.get();
    c.setTimeInMillis(new Date().getTime());
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using java 8's LocalTime

```
LocalTime time = Instant.ofEpochMilli(longValue)
    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .toLocalTime();
System.out.println(time.getHour());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not about efficiency it's about thread safety. Calendar class is not thread safe, it means that modifying the same Calendar class instance across multiple threads may lead you to undetermined results. As long as  every thread has dedicated Calendar instance (that is not shared with other threads) everything should be fine.

Couple of words about thread safety:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076747/core-java/design-for-thread-safety.html

About Calendar class:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245086/1529940

You may also want to have a look into Joda-Time library or new Time API in Java8